# Wordpress running from one subfolder and app from another

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

How do I redirect ‘app’ to the separate folder if I’m already redirecting everything else to ‘wordpress’?

At the moment my WordPress works well from public_html/wordpress/ but when I access mydomain.io/app/ I would like to serve the app from public_html/app/

Here is my folder structure:

```
   public_html/wordpress/
   public_html/app/
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ “http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/” [R=301,L]

#Redirect to subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1
```

I tried this but does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com\/app*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../app/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" with what you tried on the redirection? What happens?

Comment: IT shows WP not found page

Comment: What if you just get rid of this part? `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com\/app*$`

Comment: I also tried: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L] - the same result

Comment: @Difster I get Bad Request

Comment: I'm no expert, But put the app rules first and make the rule stop if executed with `[L]` flag. Rules execute from top to bottom. So Your 1st rule always gets executed first hence executing wordpress index file and causing WP page not found

Comment: Try This as 1st rule: `RewriteRule ^.*www\.mydomain\.com/app/(.*) /app/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting should work for Wordpress in the `/wordpress` subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine on
#app rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]

#wordpress rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L]
```

and analogically you can alter the rules for the `/app` subfolder depending on your app needs.

Comment: My .htaccess is directly in /public_html

Comment: I understood - it's .htaccess config for /public_html location

Comment: so when I access http://example.com I get redirected to /wordpress/ - this part works from my example

Comment: the part which does not is example.com/app to be redirected to /app/

Comment: So I commented out my wordpress redirect and added yours and it works with the rest of my app code..crazy Thanks

Comment: I altered my answer - /app/ goes into the /app subdir, everything else to the /wordpress subdir. If you want opposite behaviour, then interchange the app and the wordpress config.